# Log-likelihood of multinomial(?) distribution

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

If i have 3 probability groups of $p_1(\theta):p_2(\theta):p_3(\theta)=(1-\theta):(1+2\theta):(1-\theta)$ with $n_1=31,n_2=47,n_3=22$ how would I find the log-likelihood of above and MLE of $\theta$?

I think this is a multinomial question with probability function of
 $f(x|p)=\frac{n!}{\prod x_i}\prod p_i^x$ so I went ahead and calculated log likelihood to be $l(p)=ln(n!)+\sum ln(x_i) +\sum x_i ln(p_i)$ but now i'm stuck with finding MLE. I get $0=\sum \frac{x_i}{p_i}$ so did I derive the likelihood or differentiate wrong? Or am I using the wrong distribution?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of errors and omissions in your statements:

- Your log-likelihood would have been better as $$\ln(n!)-\sum \ln(n_i!) +\sum_i n_i \ln(p_i)$$
- You need to take into account that $\sum\limits_i p_i =1$ and $\sum\limits_i n_i =n$, particularly the former
- Your derivative appears to be with respect to all of the $p_i$ simultaneously in some sense that does not work

If instead you had the log-likelihood written as  $$\ln(n!)-\sum \ln(n_i!) + n_1 \ln(p_1)+ n_2 \ln(p_2) +  n_3 \ln(1-p_1-p_2)$$ then taking the derivative with respect to $p_1$ and setting it to $0$ would suggest $\frac{n_1}{\hat p_1}-\frac{n_3}{1-\hat p_1-\hat p_2}=0$ and similarly taking the derivative with respect to $p_2$ and setting it to $0$ would suggest $\frac{n_2}{\hat p_2}-\frac{n_3}{1-\hat p_1-\hat p_2}=0$. Rearranging these and combining with the second point above would lead to
$$\hat p_1 = \frac{n_1}{n}, \;\hat p_2 = \frac{n_2}{n},\; \hat p_3 = \frac{n_3}{n}$$

---

*Added*

I had missed the $\theta$ and that this means $\hat p_1=\hat p_3$.  Note that $(1-\theta)+(1+2\theta)+(1-\theta)=3$

So your log-likelihood would have been better as
$$\ln(100!)- \ln(31!)- \ln(47!)- \ln(22!) \\+ 31 \ln(1-\theta)+47\ln(1+2 \theta) +22\ln(1-\theta) -100 \ln(3)$$

Take the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and get $$-\frac{53}{1-\theta}+\frac{94}{1+2\theta}$$ which is zero when $\hat \theta = \dfrac{41}{200}$

This gives $\hat p_1=\hat p_3 = 0.265$ and $\hat p_2=0.47$, which is intuitively attractive with the former as the average of the sample proportions $\frac{31}{100}$ and $\frac{22}{100}$, and the latter as the sample proportion $\frac{47}{100}$

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. I understand most of what you're saying but still a bit confused with the probabilities. It makes sense that $\sum p_i=1$ so why is it then the probabilities given to me add up to $3$ ($1-\theta +1+2\theta +1-\theta $)? Or am i completely misunderstanding the question? Also you found the MLEs of $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ so to find the MLE of $\theta$ would I substitute $p_1(\theta)$ into $\frac{n_1}{n}$ and repeat for all 3 p's, giving me 3 MLE of $\theta\s?

Comment: I had missed the $\theta$

Comment: And what if I were to find the asymptotic std. err. of MLE $\theta$ and a 95% confidence interval of $\theta$? I figured I need to find the inverse of $\mathbb{E}[-l''(\theta)]$ so i get $\frac{188}{1+4\theta +4\theta ^2} - \frac{53}{1-2\theta +\theta^2}$ but how do i incorporate the expected value?

Comment: You can use the binomial distribution to find those for $\hat p_2$ and then translate these for $\hat \theta$

Comment: I tried it and got the std err. as 0.0749. Did you get that too?